# Image does not maintain x,y coordinates during drag and drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, coordinates

I am trying to set up drag and drop functionality for an imageView onLongClick. The issue I am noticing is that for the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED`, the received X and Y cords from the event change from the last `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION` coordinates. This causes the draggable imageView to move (or jump) after I have dropped it. Here is my implementation.

First I setup an onLongClickListener on the object (imageView) I want to drag around:

```
ivDrag.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),
                mimeTypes, item);
                DragShadowBuilder mShadow = new DragShadowBuilder(v);
                v.startDrag(dragData, mShadow, v, 0); 
                dragView.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I then set an onDragListener on the object (imageView) I want to drag around:

```
    ivDrag.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (event.getAction()) {
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
             layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
             Logger.i(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
             ivDrag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             break;          
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
             containDragable = true;
             Logger.i(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
             x_cord = (int) event.getX();
             y_cord = (int) event.getY();
             Logger.i(TAG, "x_cord: " + x_cord + " //y_cord: " + y_cord);   
             break;      
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
             containDragable = false;
             Logger.i(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
             x_cord = (int) event.getX(); // removing this line allows correct cords
             y_cord = (int) event.getY(); // removing this line allows correct cords
             Logger.d(TAG, "x_cord: " + x_cord + " //y_cord: " + y_cord);

             // below re-positions the drag object
             layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
             layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
             v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);        
             break;      
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
             Logger.i(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
             x_cord = (int) event.getX();
             y_cord = (int) event.getY();
             Logger.i(TAG, "x_cord: " + x_cord + " //y_cord: " + y_cord);
             break;          
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED :
             Logger.i(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
             // below is what makes sure the image does not disappear
             ivDrag.post(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Logger.e(TAG, "inside runnable");
                     if (ivDrag.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                         ivDrag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     }
                 }       
             });         
             break;
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
             Logger.i(TAG, "ACTION_DROP event");
             // Do nothing
             break;
         default:
             break;
         }
         return true;
         }
    });
}
```

Note: As commented above if I remove the update for x,y cords from `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED`, the logs indicate the correct coordinates. However, I then am unable to re-drag the object after that.

Lastly, I create a listener for when I have dragged the object into the container.

```
private View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {  
    @Override 
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {    
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Logger.v(TAG, "drag started (onDrag)");
            break; 
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Logger.v(TAG, "drag entered (onDrag)");
            break; 
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Logger.v(TAG, "drag exited (onDrag)");
            break; 
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Logger.e(TAG, "drop (onDrag)");
            // handle drop 
            break; 
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Logger.v(TAG, "drag ended (onDrag)");
            break; 
        default: 
            return false; 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 
};
```

What am I missing to make this work as expected? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let see if I get it write: are you setting the LayoutParams to the same ImageView you dragging?

Comment: I was setting the layoutParams to the parent view actually. Is it suppose to be the drag object?

Comment: Why you changing the values of the LayoutParams during the drag process and not just in the ACTION_DROP? And what you mean in the words: "However, I then am unable to re-drag the object after that."

Comment: I do not change during the drag process, the layout params are not set until drag_exited. And I mean just as I said, not updating the new x,y will result in me maintaining the correct x,y cords, however, by not updating the cords the object can no longer be dragged. The object stays in one place.

Comment: I will experiment with setting the layoutparams in action drop as you suggested. Maybe that is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @portfoliobuilder any luck with this? Got the same issue, in addition to the draggable view shrinking as soon as it gets too close to it's parents borders (FrameLayout being the parent). As for your other issue, that you can't drag anymore after dropping: Did you make sure the OnTouchListener that triggers the drag & drop is still attached to the image view when dropping it? In my case I am cloning draggables so I always need to re-attach the TouchListener to the cloned imageview

Comment: One more thing: I am setting my final layout params in the DragEvent.ACTION_DROP - this should be the last event - any reason you're setting your layout params in DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED ? Plus your Drag listener should be on the target layout, not on the view that you are dragging around.

Comment: Yes, I resolved this. I needed to remove my views from parent and then re-add them. I was able to find a good example online from another project. Maybe it can help you out too. Here is the link, https://github.com/drxeno02/kids-education-spelling/blob/master/EekSpellingI/src/com/blog/ljtatum/eekspellingi/activity/PictureDropActivity.java